# Catch Revert message

Tags: remix, blockchain

How to catch revert messages from another contract using call method?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Logiccontract{
    string public datas;

    function changename(address add, string memory name)public{
         (bool send,bytes memory data)=add.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(Istorage.set.selector,name));
         
         console.log("status",send);
     

    }
     function changeOwner(address add, address _owner)public{
         (bool send,)=add.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(Istorage.setOwner.selector, _owner));
    }



}
```

---

```
interface Istorage{
     function setOwner(address _owner)external;
     function set(string memory _name)external;

}
```

---

```
contract Storagecontract{
    address public owner;
    constructor(address _owner){
     owner=_owner;
    }
   string public name="sreeshma";

   modifier  onlyOwner(){
    require(owner==msg.sender,"only owner can call");
    _;
   }

   function setOwner(address _owner)public {
    
    owner=_owner;

   }
    
    function set(string memory _name)public {
        console.log(owner,msg.sender);

        require(owner==msg.sender,"only owner can call");
        console.log(owner,msg.sender);
        name=_name;
    }
}
```

when call the set function with another account other than owner we didn't get revert message